# Parsing JSON dict of CloudFormation parameters for '--parameter-overrides'

Tags: jq

I'm using AWS CloudFormation at the moment, and I need to parse out parameters due to differences between stack creation and deployment. Command `aws cloudformation create` accepts a JSON file, but `aws cloudformation deploy` only accepts inlined application parameters of `Key=Value` type.

I have this JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "ParameterKey": "EC2KeyPair",
        "ParameterValue": "$YOUR_EC2_KEY_PAIR"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "SSHLocation",
        "ParameterValue": "$YOUR_SSH_LOCATION"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "DjangoEnvVarDebug",
        "ParameterValue": "$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DEBUG"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "DjangoEnvVarSecretKey",
        "ParameterValue": "$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_SECRET_KEY"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "DjangoEnvVarDBName",
        "ParameterValue": "$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_NAME"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "DjangoEnvVarDBUser",
        "ParameterValue": "$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_USER"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "DjangoEnvVarDBPassword",
        "ParameterValue": "$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_PASSWORD"
    },
    {
        "ParameterKey": "DjangoEnvVarDBHost",
        "ParameterValue": "$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_HOST"
    }
]
```

And I want to turn it into this:

```
'EC2KeyPair=$YOUR_EC2_KEY_PAIR SSHLocation=$YOUR_SSH_LOCATION DjangoEnvVarDebug=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DEBU
G DjangoEnvVarSecretKey=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_SECRET_KEY DjangoEnvVarDBName=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_NAME D
jangoEnvVarDBUser=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_USER DjangoEnvVarDBPassword=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_PASSWORD Dj
angoEnvVarDBHost=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_HOST'
```

This would be the equivalent Python code:

```py
thing = json.load(open('stack-params.example.json', 'r'))
convert = lambda item: f'{item["ParameterKey"]}={item["ParameterValue"]}'

>>> print(list(map(convert, thing)))                 
['EC2KeyPair=$YOUR_EC2_KEY_PAIR', 'SSHLocation=$YOUR_SSH_LOCATION', 'DjangoEnvVarDebug=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_V
AR_DEBUG', 'DjangoEnvVarSecretKey=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_SECRET_KEY', 'DjangoEnvVarDBName=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_
VAR_DB_NAME', 'DjangoEnvVarDBUser=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_USER', 'DjangoEnvVarDBPassword=$YOUR_DJANGO_EN$
_VAR_DB_PASSWORD', 'DjangoEnvVarDBHost=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_HOST']

>>> ' '.join(map(convert, thing))
'EC2KeyPair=$YOUR_EC2_KEY_PAIR SSHLocation=$YOUR_SSH_LOCATION DjangoEnvVarDebug=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DEBU
G DjangoEnvVarSecretKey=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_SECRET_KEY DjangoEnvVarDBName=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_NAME D
jangoEnvVarDBUser=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_USER DjangoEnvVarDBPassword=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_PASSWORD Dj
angoEnvVarDBHost=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_HOST'
```

I have this little snippet:

```sh
$ cat stack-params.example.json | jq '.[] | "\(.ParameterKey)=\(.ParameterValue)"'
"EC2KeyPair=$YOUR_EC2_KEY_PAIR"
"SSHLocation=$YOUR_SSH_LOCATION"
"DjangoEnvVarDebug=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DEBUG"
"DjangoEnvVarSecretKey=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_SECRET_KEY"
"DjangoEnvVarDBName=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_NAME"
"DjangoEnvVarDBUser=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_USER"
"DjangoEnvVarDBPassword=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_PASSWORD"
"DjangoEnvVarDBHost=$YOUR_DJANGO_ENV_VAR_DB_HOST"
```

But I'm not sure how to join the strings together. I was looking at reduce but I think it only works on lists, and streams of strings aren't lists. So I'm thinking the correct approach is to convert the key : value association into 'key=value' strings within the list, then join altogether, though I have trouble working with the regex. Does anybody have any tips?

Comment: you could join lines via `paste`, e.g. `... | paste -s -d' ' -`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal as exemplified by the illustrative output seems highly dubious, but it can easily be achieved using the -r command-line option together with the filter:

```
map("\(.ParameterKey)=\(.ParameterValue)") | "'" + join(" ") + "'"
```

### Footnote

> I was looking at reduce but I think it only works on lists, and streams of strings aren't lists.

To use `reduce` on a list, say $l, you could simply use [] as in:

```
reduce $l[] as $x (_;_)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! I haven't worked professionally in a DevOps capacity, and I'm building an MVP out. Do you have any best practices recommendations for minimizing drift for configuration management in production? I'd love to learn more.